# How long does Spike Trap last?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

How long does an un-activated [Spike Trap](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/spike-trap) remain on the ground ready to be triggered, and does it depand on anything other than just duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked and an un-activated Spike Trap can last up to 30 seconds. Leaving the dungeon (either transitioning a floor or teleporting out with a town portal / waypoint) will cause the Spike Trap to disappear.

Laying the 4th (or 7th, with Bandolier) trap will immediately make the oldest one disappear.

Answer (score 1):

There's no maximum length as to how long it remains there, so as long as the game instance is available or maybe when you change acts/zones.  You can only have a maximum of three, however.